# How to clear values inside modal form in vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a modal with a small form (Select and list with multiple select). I can save my values. But after saving I want to close the modal and while closing clear every form field in this case my list selection and selectbox values, right now they are still the first value I selected before closing. Could someone give me a pointer on how to do it?

I thought of putting everything inside a form tag and maybe trying to achieve it from their, but do not know if it is a correct way. these are the selections I want to clear. The binded arrays I can already clear out. But not the select in the list

html:

```
 <v-row>
        <v-col cols="4" >
          <v-select
              :items="availableTimes"
              item-text="date"
              @select="filterByDate"
              v-model="selectedDate"
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="8">
          <v-chip-group
              v-model="selection"
              active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4">
            <v-chip
                v-for="(time, i) in dateTimeArray"
                :key="time.id"
                :value="time"
                v-on:click="getTimeValue(times)"
                @click="getTimesFiltered(time)">
              {{ time.startTime +" - "+ time.endTime }}
            </v-chip>
          </v-chip-group>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
      <v-col cols="4">
        <v-card>
        <v-list>
        <v-list-item-group
            v-model="model"
            multiple
            color="blue"
        >
          <v-list-item
              v-for="(item, i) in voterArrayFilteredByTime"
              :key="item.id"
              :value="item">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.voterUniqueName"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>

        </v-card>
```

Comment: Why can't you just set the `v-model`s to the initial value (or `null`)?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you show your script tags.

Without seeing what you are trying to do, my suggestion would be to use reset your "selection" variable in your methods. For example if you have a close button

```
<v-btn @click="resetStuff" >Close me<v-btn>
```

Then in your method:

```
  methods: {
    // your method
    resetStuff() {
    this.selection = null
    //.. some more variables to reset 

  }
```